# Can indexing a MySQL column improve a LIKE search?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using a table that I downloaded elsewhere, and they put a column called `DATA_SOURCE` which concatenates all the different data sources of a record like so:

`sourceA; sourceB; sourceC; ...`

So, if I am looking for records from `sourceB`, I would have to do a like search on `%sourceB%`.

This is obviously a time-consuming query. My question is, if I were to index column `DATA_SOURCE`, would it improve the performance of these wildcard like searches? Or would it not make a difference.

Comment: You would be better off restructuring this into [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) then you would be able to index it satisfactorily.

Comment: I agree, thanks Martin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Indexes **will** be used on like searches, but **only** if the search criterium **does not begin** with a wildcard.

So `LIKE 'Albert %'` will be indexable, while `LIKE '%Einstein%'` will not.

Reason for this is of course that all an index does is construct an internal table of where the results are when sorted by that column, to reduce a search from linear to logarithmic complexity. If the search criterium starts with a wildcard it will still have to loop through all possible values to match them (a so-called *table scan*), thus eliminating the potential performance gain of an index.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I had thought, wanted to be sure :-)

Comment: Actually my answer isn't yet *entirely* complete: given that you only want to search for full words if I understand the question correctly, a full text index could actually work if you're using MyISAM for storage. This would of course be an extremely hacky workaround for not normalizing properly as suggested elsewhere, but it could work if technical constraints prohibit a fundamentally better solution.

Comment: We use InnoDB everywhere, so probably not a good idea to switch in this one instance. I think, as you mention, a better idea is to create a separate lookup table for data source, and join on that.